# Apache avro code generation POJO only

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, avro, pojo

I want to automatically create classes based on previously defined schema files in my Java project.
To accomplish this I have used Avro Maven plugin.

The problem is that generated classes are not pure POJO objects - there are also avro references which I dont want in my data model (want to keep it simple):

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser;
import org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase;
```

Is there way to generate only POJO object? Are avro references required for serialization/deserialization process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to generate POJO using avro maven plugin or avro-tools.jar without avro stuff.

It is how these tools work, and of course these imports are not necessary for normal serialization/deserialization, so if don't need them - the best way out is to use some another lib/plugin to generate POJO.